# Problem III.2.14 in Analysis I by Amann: open (closed) functions between metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, metric-spaces

Good afternoon, I'm doing Problem *III.2.14* from textbook **Analysis I** by Amann.

> [image]

**My attempt:**

(a)

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ be open w.r.t $d$. For $y \in A$, the open ball $\mathbb B_\delta (y, 1/2) = \{y\} \subseteq A$. As such, $\operatorname{id}[A]= A$ is open w.r.t $\delta$. Hence $\operatorname{id}$ is open.

Let $B \subseteq \mathbb R$ be closed w.r.t $d$. Then $\mathbb R - B$ is open w.r.t $d$. As such, $\operatorname{id}[\mathbb R - B]= \mathbb R - B$ is open w.r.t $\delta$ and thus $\operatorname{id}[B] = B$ is closed w.r.t $\delta$. Hence $\operatorname{id}$ is closed.

For $x \in \mathbb R$ and $U$ is an arbitrary neighborhood of $x$ w.r.t $d$. Then $U -\{x\} \neq \emptyset$. For $x' \in (U -\{x\})$ , we have $d_\delta (x',x) = 1$. As such, $f$ is discontinuous at any $x \in \mathbb R$.

(b)

Let $x \in \mathbb R$ and $U$ be an arbitrary neighborhood of $\operatorname{id}(x)$ w.r.t $d$. We have $\operatorname{id}[\mathbb B_\delta (x, 1/2)] = \operatorname{id}[\{x\}] = \{x\} = \{\operatorname{id}(x)\} \subseteq U$. As such, $\operatorname{id}$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

For $x \in \mathbb R$, $\operatorname{id}[\mathbb B_\delta (x, 1/2)] = \operatorname{id}[\{x\}] = \{x\}$. On the other hand, $\mathbb B_\delta (x, 1/2)$ is open w.r.t $\delta$ and $\{x\}$ is not open w.r.t $d$. As such, $\operatorname{id}$ is not open.

For $x \in \mathbb R$, $\mathbb B_\delta (x, 1/2)$ is open w.r.t $\delta$. Then $\mathbb R - \mathbb B_\delta (x, 1/2)$ is closed w.r.t $\delta$. We have $\operatorname{id} [\mathbb R - \mathbb B_\delta (x, 1/2)] = \mathbb R - \operatorname{id} [\mathbb B_\delta (x, 1/2)] = \mathbb R - \{\operatorname{id}(x)\} = \mathbb R - \{x\}$, which is not closed w.r.t $d$. As such, $\operatorname{id}$ is not closed.

---

**My questions:**

1. Could you please verify if my proof look fine or contains logical gaps/errors? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

2.

**Lemma:** Any one element subset of a metric space is closed.

We have $\mathbb B_\delta (y, 1/2)$ is an open ball w.r.t $\delta$. Moreover, $\mathbb B_\delta (y, 1/2) = \{y\}$, which is closed w.r.t $\delta$ by our **Lemma**. As such, $\mathbb B_\delta (y, 1/2)$ is both open and closed w.r.t $\delta$.

Could you please confirm if my understanding is correct? Thank you so much!

Comment: The proof seems good! Another way to prove discontinuity in (1) is by using the fact that a function is continuous if and only if the inverse images of open sets are open. If we take the inverse image of $\left\lbrace x \right\rbrace$, which is open in $\left( X, \delta \right)$, it is not open in $\left( X, d \right)$. Hence, $id$ will not be continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is fine. In order to prove that $\operatorname{id}\colon(\mathbb R,\delta)\longrightarrow(\mathbb R,d)$ is neither open nor closed, I would just say that, for instance, $[0,1)$ is both open and closed in $(\mathbb R,\delta)$, but it is neither open nor closed in $(\mathbb R,d)$.